# Showing several images at the same time

Tags: html, image

i do a app and i want to show two images. one under the other.

i have tried a lots of things with data role content but i dont know what i doing wrong.

any idea?

my html5 code:

```
<div data-role="page" id="p3">
<div data-role="content" id="Orienthorizontal" style="padding:0px;">
        <img src="imagens/Horizontal/6.jpg"/>
         <a href="#positionWindow" id="videoicon" data-rel="popup" data-inline="true" data-transition="slidefade" data-position-to="window"><img src="icon/video-icon.png"/></a>
    </div>
<div data-role="content" id="Orienthorizontal" style="padding:0px;">
        <img src="imagens/Horizontal/6.2.jpg"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#Orienthorizontal{position:absolute}
```

Comment: major problem: dom ID's must be unique for a given document. you've got two elements with the same ID. that's a no-no. as for the position: absolute? why? do you mean "under the other" as in literally one on top of the other? same x/y coordinates, different Z? or visually on top, so that the bottom edge of one image touches the top of the other?

Comment: Yep, Marc B is right.  Change your two id="OrientHorizontal"'s to class="Orienthorizontal" and then in your CSS, change #Orienthorizontal to .OrientHorizontal.

Comment: mhh.  sorry for my mistakes.. im new in this area.. but what i tried is one image in the top and when i scroll are the other image

Comment: cant fixed it.. help me pls

Answer (score 0):

Either define your CSS such that the divs must display on separate lines, or you can simply insert a `<br/>` tag between them to force a line break.